# Can one pass a code string into a C\C++-macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros

For example I'd like to make a debug macro which prints a code string before attempting to execute it. I suppose it should look something like that

```
#define TRACE(string) printf("Trying to execute: %s\n",\"string\"); \
                      string

...

void foo() {
  printf("1\n");
}
void bar() {
  printf("2\n");
}

int main() {
  ...
  foo();
  TRACE(bar(););
  ...
}
```

With expected output

```
...
1
Trying to execute: bar();
2
...
```

Well, THIS is not how one does it: compiler complains about illegal syntax. Is there a way to do it at all?

Comment: C does't support strings like that. Research a Char Array and you will find the solution

Comment: Said in answers... Need `#` but moreover, the last semicolon will cause `bar();;`

Comment: if your use-case is debugging. i recommend trying GDB

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use stringification using `#`:

```
#define TRACE(string) printf("Trying to execute: %s\n",#string); \
                      string
```

**Full example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRACE(string) printf("Trying to execute: %s\n",#string); \
                          string

void foo() {
  printf("1\n");
}
void bar() {
  printf("2\n");
}

int main() {

  foo();
  TRACE(bar(););
}
```

**output:**

```
1
Trying to execute: bar();
2
```

<kbd>[live example on ideone](https://ideone.com/OBktuV)</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

You must use the "stringification" operator, `#`, which will cause substitution with `"string"`.

```
#define TRACE(string) printf("Trying to execute: %s\n", #string); \
                      string
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answers, wrap your macro around a `do { /* ... */ } while(0)` construct, as in:

```
#define TRACE(string) do { \
                          printf("Trying to execute: %s\n", #string); \
                          string \
                      } while(0)
```

Otherwise, it may cause errors, e.g.

```
if(condition)
    TRACE(foo();)
```

If you do not wrap it around a `do { /* ... */ } while(0)` construct, `foo()` will be called even if `condition` is false. If you have an `else` statement following, it will even cause a syntax error.

For more information, see [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/3488231).